# Adding 1 day to a date value in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a case in a SQL Developer query

x & y are both date values:

```
CASE
    WHEN x.cre_dttm <= y.cc_dttm
    THEN 'y_after_x_cre'
    ELSE 'y_before_x_cre'
  END "something"
```

The is I want the logic to be "x.cre_dttm <= y.cc_dttm + 1 day"

```
CASE
    WHEN x.cre_dttm <= y.cc_dttm + 1 day
    THEN 'y_after_x_cre'
    ELSE 'y_before_x_cre'
  END "something"
```

I've tried searching and I can't find anything that directly answers my question as to how I would accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use `DATEADD` function in oracle

```
  CASE
    WHEN x.cre_dttm <= DATEADD(Day,1,y.cc_dttm) 
    THEN 'y_after_x_cre'
    ELSE 'y_before_x_cre'
  END "something"
```

[SOURCE](http://sql-plsql.blogspot.in/2010/07/dateadd.html)